# How to use btree/plus in Workiva/go-datastructures/

Tags: go, package, binary-tree

I have been needing an implementation of a binary plus tree. I found one here.

- https://github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures/tree/master/btree/plus

But I am not exactly sure how to use it. The other data structures in this repo are quite straightforward. Simply call he package and run the methods. But this btree one is a little confusing

I just want a quick example of how to create, insert and retrieve from the tree created by this package.

1. create btree/plus
2. insert keys
3. retrieve range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures/btree/plus) for it says "As of this writing, the tree is not quite finished", and it doesn't seem to expose a public interface for creating a tree at all. Functions like `newBtree` and `get` [exist in the source](https://github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures/blob/master/btree/plus/btree.go) but are private, as you can see from the names.

[An old benchmark of btree packages](https://github.com/tv42/benchmark-ordered-map) also serves as a set of pointers to various ordered collection packages. [google/btree](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/btree) is from Google. [cznic/b](https://godoc.org/github.com/cznic/b) is a B+ tree as `btree/plus` was/is planned to be, and also offers the option to do code generation instead of using `interface`s.